# Exercises for glutes?

Tags: lower-body-strength, glutes

Glutes are the biggest muscle on our body. I know that someone is going to suggest leg press or the squat for working them, but I am seeking an exercise, primarily with weights, that hits your glute muscles. I would prefer if not to be the bridge because the position looks uncomfortable. Any exercises to bulk glutes?

Comment: Why are you avoiding the squat?

Comment: I'm not avoiding the squat, in fact I squat 3 times a week. I'm just wondering about a specific exercise that hits the glutes, and squats focus on the quads more.

Comment: Indeed. I wouldn't worry too much and just focus on progressing with the squat and the glutes will follow naturally. Nevertheless, I see lots of people (mainly girls) doing glute exercises for instance in the smith machine.

Answer (score 1):

From [Bret Contreras](https://www.t-nation.com/training/dispelling-the-glute-myth) (a.k.a. The Glute Guy):

> Squatting, deadlifting, and lunging, can make the glutes sore but they
>   don't strengthen the glutes much. They target the quads and erector
>   spinae. Even box squatting, walking lunges, and sumo deadlifts don't
>   activate much glute in comparison to the exercises below.

Basically you could do weighted (on your ankle) [bird dogs](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/ErectorSpinae/BWBirdDog.html) or the [glute ham device](http://www.roguefitness.com/strength-equipment/strength-training/ghds).

The [barbell glute bridge](http://www.bodybuilding.com/exercises/detail/view/name/barbell-glute-bridge) is far-and-away superior to both of those for glute development. It's not that uncomfortable once you get it figured out.

Comment: I find all the discomfort goes away when I combine a bar pad and a folded up yoga mat and keep the bar locked into my hip crease.